# How to run Kafka in the cloud (pykafka)?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I had to connect Kafka and MQTT. In order to do that I have used python (pykafka to be specific) and a mosquitto broker to create a bridge application between them.

My infrastructure looks like this: I have a DHT11 temperature sensor connected to an ESP8266 which is my source for data. From ESP8266 I am sending data to the Mosquitto MQTT broker and further to Apache Kafka. Now as long as I run it locally (both mosquitto and kafka) everything is working fine, but I am trying to set up a fog(cloud)-like infrastructure prototype and measure the latencies.

To simulate the fog-cloud infrastructure I am (still) running Mosquitto on my local machine but I am trying to run Kafka on a Microsoft Azure instance and when I try it, it doesn't work.

What I have tried is: taking the replacing "hosts" parameter which was originally `127.0.0.1:9092` with my public IP address of the Azure instance like in the code below.

```
class KafkaClient(object):
    A high-level pythonic client for Kafka
    def __init__(self,
                 hosts='11.44.218.185:9092', 
                 use_greenlets=False,
                 socket_timeout_ms=30 * 1000,
                 offsets_channel_socket_timeout_ms=10 * 1000,
                 ignore_rdkafka=False,
                 exclude_internal_topics=True,
                 source_address=''):
        Create a connection to a Kafka cluster.
```

And then in my program i created an instance of it:

```
kafka_client = KafkaClient(hosts="11.44.218.185:9092")
```

Answer (score 1):

[PyKafka](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka) is no longer maintained; use a different library.

There is nothing unique about using **any Kafka client** to connect to a Kafka broker. You need to [ensure that your broker's `advertised.listeners` are resolvable at the address you've provided](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/). Regarding Azure, make sure the VPC allows for external connections and that port 9092 is open on the broker instance.

Comment: ye that's easier said than done. The whole application is written using pykafka. It would just be out of scope to try to use another library. Like i said i am just looking for a way to use my application for measuring latency. I've opened the 9092 port on the virtual machine, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So, 9092 is open, then set on the broker `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` and `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external.vm.ip:9092`, and you should be good to go, regardless of the client being used. I'd suggest testing with `kcat` or `kafka-console-*.sh` tools, though

Comment: I suppose i should use the external IP when creating a consumer aswell? Like instead of .\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic temperature something like this .\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server externalIP:9092 --topic temperature?

Comment: Unless you've ssh'd into the broker instances, then yes